# Creating a method with strings and loops

Tags: java, string, loops, stringbuilder

I am trying to create a method that will take two strings and return one string that has replaced the words in between parentheses from string 1 with those in parentheses in string 2, but I am running into problems which I can't seem to understand. As an example

```
replaceText("a (simple) programming (example)", "(cool) (problem)")
```

should return

```
"a cool programming problem"
```

and

```
replaceText("a ((nested) example) with (three) replacements (to (handle))", 
            "the replacements are (answer) and (really (two) not three)")
```

should return

```
"an answer with really (two) not three replacements "
```

I can only use loops, basic String methods (.length(), .charAt()), basic StringBuilder methods to do this and Character methods, but I am running into serious difficulties.

Right now this is my code

```
public class loopStringAnalysis {

public static String replaceText (String s1, String s2){
StringBuilder newStringBuild = new StringBuilder ();
int count = 0;
int count1 = 0;
for (int i = 0, i1 = 0; i < s1.length() && i1 < s2.length(); i = i + 1){
  if (s1.charAt(i) == '(')
    count = count + 1;
  else if (s1.charAt(i) == ')')
    count = count - 1;
  else if (count == 0)
    newStringBuild.append(s1.charAt(i));
  else if (count != 0){
    while (count1 == 0) {
      if (s2.charAt(i1) == '(')
        count1 = count1 + 1;
      else if (s2.charAt(i1) == ')') 
        count1 = count1 - 1; 
      i1 = i1 + 1;
    }
    while (count1 != 0) {
      if (s2.charAt(i1) == '(')
        count1 = count1 + 1;
      else if (s2.charAt(i1) == ')')
        count1 = count1 - 1;
      else if (count1 != 0)
        newStringBuild.append(s2.charAt(i1));
      i1 = i1 + 1;
    }
    while (count != 0) {
      if (s1.charAt(i) == '(')
        count = count + 1;
      else if (s1.charAt(i) == ')')
        count = count - 1;
      i = i + 1;
    }
  }
}
return newStringBuild.toString();
}
```

For the first example this returns "a coolprogramming project", while for the second example this returns "a answerwith really two not three". I know this method has problems but I can't seem to figure where. Any help with fixing the code is appreciated.

Comment: I have some notes on [debug strategy](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/debug/index.html) that you may find useful if you want to be able to find bugs yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class loopStringAnalysis {

    public static String replaceText(String s1, String s2) {
        StringBuilder newStringBuild = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 0;
        int count1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0, i1 = 0; i < s1.length() && i1 < s2.length(); i = i + 1) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) == '(') {
                count = count + 1;
            } else if (s1.charAt(i) == ')') {
                count = count - 1;
            } else if (count == 0) {
                newStringBuild.append(s1.charAt(i));
            } else if (count != 0) {
                while (count1 == 0) {
                    if (s2.charAt(i1) == '(') {
                        count1 = count1 + 1;
                    } else if (s2.charAt(i1) == ')') {
                        count1 = count1 - 1;
                    }
                    i1 = i1 + 1;
                }
                while (count1 != 0) {
                    if (s2.charAt(i1) == '(') {
                        count1 = count1 + 1;
                    } else if (s2.charAt(i1) == ')') {
                        count1 = count1 - 1;
                    }
                    if (count1 != 0) {
                        newStringBuild.append(s2.charAt(i1));
                    }
                    i1 = i1 + 1;
                }
                while (count != 0) {
                    i = i + 1;
                    if (s1.charAt(i) == '(') {
                        count = count + 1;
                    } else if (s1.charAt(i) == ')') {
                        count = count - 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return newStringBuild.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(replaceText("a ((nested) example) with (three) replacements (to (handle))",
            "the replacements are (answer) and (really (two) not three)"));
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works?

Comment: This works perfectly for the first example I provided, but the second example only returns "a answer with really (two) not three" instead of "an answer with really (two) not three replacements ". In any case thanks for the help!!!

Comment: I'm really not a fan of code-only answers.  Could you explain *why* this would be an ideal solution?

Comment: I have been able to finish it thanks to your help!!! Just had to make some changes to the conditions and now it works perfectly. Thanks!!

P.S: I don't get why you got a downvote :(

Comment: Good to know :), I also don't know about downvote :(. But it was nice question. I have upvoted your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code that you have written so far is unnecessarily complicated. Instead of looping through the string looking for the opening and closing parens, use the String method

```
String.indexOf(char c)
```

to find the index of the parens. This way you don't have to loop through the first string. If you cannot use this method, then let me know and I can try to provide some more help.

Comment: Sadly I can't. I am restricted to using the charAt and length methods of String, the append, charAt, setCharAt, length, and toString methods of StringBuilder and methods from the character class.